# Can you explain what is going on with my little avocado tree?

Tags: diagnosis, watering, avocado

I managed to grow an avocado tree from a pit. I transplanted it to a small pot and almost once per week it looks like that:

[image]

At some point, the drooping leaves issue happened because it was next to heat source, but then I moved it away and became healthy again. Now almost once per week becomes like that. I am concerned that it may be over-watering or under-watering (with the latter being the better scenario) but I can't really tell. I water every 4-5 days, and when I decide to water it, usually the top soil is dry, while the soil below is not moist but it feels "fresh".

My pot has drainage holes, but also an integrated saucer which kinda concerns me about proper drainage.

What is your opinion and/or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not worry about the drooping. I have a few avocados from pits and one of them is constantly quite droopy like yours even after watering but otherwise quite happy. It's not because the leaves are heavy or the leaf petioles weak, it just evidently likes being like that. It could be related to the humidity in the house which is quite low right now since we are in winter here. The point really is that avocados from pits can be very variable in height, speed of germination and so on and yours just happens to have this characteristic. It sounds as though you are very attentive to good watering so no worries there.

The only comment to be made is that (and this may just be a trick of the lighting or the camera) the leaves seem to be calling for more nitrogen. Avocados should have good green leaves which make the main veins appear pale green in comparison - yours have paler leaf surfaces than the green veins. It could be that your potting soil has depleted the N content and there is none left in the pit.

When you pot up to a larger pot find a soil that is nice and rich but very free draining; avocados need to have water available but not soaking the roots. Often it is enough to take the new potting soil and thoroughly mix in a little good garden soil. Prepared soils are often free draining but assume that you will be adding your own fertilizer from there on; adding garden soil usually provides pretty well balanced nutrients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed it could be a trick of the camera because the light was quite intense (even with no sun). I will keep in mind the N stuff. Is it a good idea to use a little bit of ferilizer?